# I Am Getting Error in Android WebView URL

Tags: php, android, webview, error-handling

I have one website (using php server side) hosted that site and trying webview everything worked correctly but i used upi link in one page to redirect to upi payments ("`upi://pay?pa=*******&pn=PhonePeMerchant&cu=INR`") like this link and im getting ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME error (used in header in php)

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Can you access that URL from your server via `wget`? https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/

Comment: opened same page in mobile browser its working but in WebView its not working